# Login to remote Linux box and execute commands

Tags: shell, ssh

To delete all but 2 of the latest files in a dir running on a remote Linux box I use :

```
cd /data
ls -1tr | head -n -2 | xargs -d '\n' rm -f --
```

I execute these commands manually after logging into the remote Linux box but I'm attempting to combine login and running of these commands into a single command.

I perform something similar using `scp` where I login and scp the files to local machine at dir `/local/data` :

```
scp -i LightsailDefaultKey-eu-west-2.pem -r ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/data/ /local/data
```

Is there a method to perform something similar to above where login and commands :

```
cd /data
ls -1tr | head -n -2 | xargs -d '\n' rm -f --
```

are executed in a single command on remote machine from local machine ?

Comment: You've tagged with [tag:ssh] so you're aware of that command. What didn't work for you?

Comment: [You shouldn't parse output of ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) but anyway you might be looking for this: `ssh host 'cd /data ; ls -1tr ...'`

Comment: Answering a slightly different question, but maybe `rsync --remove-source-files` to copy the files and then remove them after they have been transferred may be what you are looking for.

Comment: [Don't Parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).   Use find instead, e.g. with GNU versions of find, sort, head, and cut: `ssh -i LightsailDefaultKey-eu-west-2.pem ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'find /data/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%Cs\t%p\0" | sort -z -nr | head -z -n 2 | cut -z -f2 | xargs -0r rm -f --'`.    Every program in that pipeline uses NUL-separated input, so will work with any filenames containing any characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with other posters you shouldn't use `ls` for this kind of parsing, but since what you have works for what you're doing, can't you just use the -d switch in your `ls` command to get the full directory path?

No reason to change your working directory unless you're doing much more work. Note you'll need to add that wildcard.

```
ssh user@host "ls -d1tr /data/* | head -n -2 | xargs -d '\n' rm -f --"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `find` rather than `ls`.  See [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).
2. wrap the commands you want to run on the remote system in quotes (but note that there may be difficulties with nested quotes) or in a here document.

e.g. using GNU versions of `find`, `sort`, `head`, and `cut`:

```
ssh -i LightsailDefaultKey-eu-west-2.pem ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx \
  'find /data/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%Ts\t%p\0" | sort -z -nr | 
     head -z -n 2 | cut -z -f2 | xargs -0r rm -f --'
```

Note that I used double-quotes around the printf format string instead of single-quotes.  That's because they're embedded in the single-quotes wrapping the entire pipeline of commands executed by `ssh`.   I could have used `-printf '\''%Cs\t%p\0'\''` instead, but (as there's no risk of variable interpolation etc here) it's easier to just use double-quotes.

The `-printf` format prints the file's last-modified timestamp (in seconds since the epoch, easily sorted as a number by the `sort -z -rn`), a tab, and the file's full pathname.  The `cut` removes the timestamp and the tab, leaving only the filename to pipe into `xargs`.

An alternative would be to use a [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document):

```
ssh -i LightsailDefaultKey-eu-west-2.pem ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx <<-'EOF'
    find /data/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%Ts\t%p\0' | sort -z -nr | 
      head -z -n 2 | cut -z -f2 | xargs -0r rm -f --
EOF
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but the above commands failed with no error. It did work with this command based on your comment regards double quotes : ssh -i LightsailDefaultKey-eu-west-2.pem -r ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'cd /data/; ls -1tr | head -n -2 | xargs -d "\n" rm -f --'     . So I needed to wrap \n in double quotes.

Answer (score -1):

You can't combine an `scp` command and shell commands in the same execution afaik.  The best you can do is:

```
    scp -i LightsailDefaultKey-eu-west-2.pem -r ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/data/ /local/data && \
    ssh -i LightsailDefaultKey-eu-west-2.pem -r ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/data/ /local/data bash -c "cd /data; ls -1tr | head -n -2 | xargs -d '\n' rm -f --"
```

note that I use `&&` to make sure the ssh doesn't run unless the scp succeeds - otherwise, you'll remove files you didn't sync yet.

Comment: At the point where you've launched a shell on the ssh server, you can't then initiate an scp from that terminal.  And there's no way from scp to initiate a shell.  Correct me if I'm wrong here - these have to be independent network transactions.